# Examining a protobuf message - how to get field values by name?

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I seem unable to find a way to verify the value of a field inside a protobuf message without explicitly invoking its getter.

I see examples around that make usage of `Descriptors.FieldDescriptor` instances to reach inside the message map, but they are either iterator-based or driven by field number.

Once I have the map:

```
Map<Descriptors.FieldDescriptor, Object> allFields = myMsg.getAllFields();
```

how can I get the value of field `"fieldXyz"`?

I know that I can use `myMsg.getFieldXyz()`, but this is not usable in a systematic way.

If there is no way to access field values by their names, I'd like to know what is the rationale behind this choice. I may have still to understand the protobuf "philosophy" :-)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I am not sure you are looking for `Descriptors#findFieldByName(name)`. You can try with followings:

```
FieldDescriptor fieldDescriptor = message.getDescriptorForType().findFieldByName("fieldXyz");
Object value = message.getField(fieldDescriptor);
```

Comment: This is going in a promising direction. How do I get to know which Java class I should cast the Object into? Looking at the API I only see methods that return `JavaType`, `Type` and similar.

Comment: note that the `name` here is the name from the proto declaration, i.e. `field_xyz` rather than `fieldXyz`

Comment: is there any equivalent in python?

Answer (score 16):

I know this is tagged for java but incase anyone is looking for a way to get the value in c++: (Assuming: field = FieldDescriptor* which contains a int32)

```
    int32_t value = message_1.GetReflection()->GetInt32(message_1, field);
```

It took me a while to get this and didn't find any stackoverflow references hence adding it. Hope it helps. Thanks!