# Reflection Utility to Match Only Existing Fields

Tags: java, apache, reflection, protocol-buffers, equals

In my current project, I'm setting up a utility to compare fields generated by any number of application versions to the latest application results. For example, if I send in a document containing "This is a test of the emergency broadcast system," the production version of the application might return something like:

**Sample A:**

```
`{
text: "This is a test of the emergency broadcast system",
numWords: 9
}`
```

The latest stable development version might spit out:

**Sample B:**

```
`{
text: "This is a test of the emergency broadcast system",
numWords: 9,
notes: [ "Emergency", "Urgent"],
}`
```

And the latest build might give something like:

**Sample C:**

```
`{
text: "This is a test of the emergency broadcast system",
numWords: 9,
notes: [ "Emergency", "Urgent"],
subSentences: [
               sentence1: { text: "This is a test.",
                            numWords: 4 }
              ]
}`
```

The utility stores what it expects the application to return and a struct that contains A) the field it is attempting to compare and B) a list of these structs containing any sub fields. For example, I might want to make sure that the `text` of every `subSentence` matches. I can do this if I know the name of each field but...

The problem is that, in order to support extensibility, the software uses protobuf, and I must use reflection. I can make no assumption as to the contents of any object an application will return. The only information I have is that list of field names. If I'd like to make sure that the latest build gets the `numWords` for the entire sentence correct, for example, I'd pass the utility the object provided by the application, and a list of strings containing the entry `numWords.`

This poses two problems:

1. The `EqualsBuilder` provided by the Apache commons (version 3.9 as of writing this) checks every field as default. This isn't useful in my case because if I'm expecting Sample A and only checking `numWords` and text, the utility should pass it. But `EqualsBuilder.reflectEquals(Sample A, Sample B)` will not return true, since Sample B has an entirely new field.
2. EqualsBuilder provides `.append()` methods to compare only specified fields, which sounds more along what I need... except for nested data objects. The API only supports appending common types, so I can easily only check `numWords` by doing `EqualsBuilder.append(9).isEqual(Sample A)`, but there's no way to do something like `EqualsBuilder.append(subSentence)` and use that as a comparison.

So, I think my question boils down to: Is there any way to compare fields based off field *names* instead of field values? And if not, is there any way to pull out internal structures without knowing anything about them (except that they exist)?

Comment: there's `java.lang.reflect.Field#getName` if that helps

Comment: I think my issue stems from how Protobuf formats it's fields. When I try to use `.getClass().getFields()` the list contains only `public static final int package.class.NUM_WORDS_NUMBER` probably containing the number assigned in the .proto file.

Comment: Try using `getDeclaredFields` instead. This returns all fields rather than only the public ones.

Comment: Same issue, only the enum-esque _FIELD_NUMBER ints show up.

I'm looking for something similar to the answer for this [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38071689/examining-a-protobuf-message-how-to-get-field-values-by-name, except the solution provided requires  casting to a particular object in order to use the `getDescriptorForType()` method